# Adding multiple rewrite cases to .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

My webroot has two directories. One is called 'functions', and the other is called 'site'. I have added an '.htaccess' to the webroot along with the other two directories. There can be two types of incoming requests, request to view a page or request to use an api.

Now, I want a check on the .htaccess that checks if the request_uri contains '/api/' in it. If it contains, the request needs to be forwarded to the 'functions' directory.  For every other request (i.e. any request_uri that does not contain '/api') the request needs to be forwarded to the 'site' directory.

I await help writing this.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.  Add the following to your `/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on


#if Request_uri string contains "/api/" forward the request to /function dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /function%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
# else redirect the request to /site directory
#redirect all other requests except /site and /api to /site directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(site|api) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

In the second Rule we excluded `/site` directory from the rule to avoid rewriting `/site/` requests to `/site` .

Note : The second rule also rewrites your homepage `/` to `/site` .If you don't want to redirect your home directory then simply  change the Rule's pattern to `^.+$` .